# What would this Moq code look like in RhinoMocks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking, rhino-mocks, moq

Hey people... trying to get my mocking sorted with asp.net MVC.

I've found this example on the net using Moq, basically I'm understanding it to say: when ApplyAppPathModifier is called, return the value that was passed to it.

I cant figure out how to do this in Rhino Mocks, any thoughts?

```
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
response.Expect(res => res.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns((string virtualPath) => virtualPath);
```

Comment: This may actually work, just testing now... its sods law, once you post a question you then find an answer... will confirm

            SetupResult
                .For<string>(response.ApplyAppPathModifier(Arg<String>.Is.Anything)).IgnoreArguments()
                .Do((Func<string, string>)((arg) => { return arg; }));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned above, sods law, once you post for help you find it 5 min later (even after searching for a while). Anyway for the benefit of others this works:

```
SetupResult
    .For<string>(response.ApplyAppPathModifier(Arg<String>.Is.Anything)).IgnoreArguments()
    .Do((Func<string, string>)((arg) => { return arg; }));
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the stub method as opposed to the SetupResult method, then the syntax for this is below:

```
response.Stub(res => res.ApplyAppPathModifier(Arg<String>.Is.Anything))
                .Do(new Func<string, string>(s => s));
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misreading the code, I think you can simplify that down quite a bit.  Try this:

```
var response = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpResponseBase>();

response.Stub(res => res.ApplyAppPathModifier(Arg<String>.Is.Anything)) 
                        .IgnoreArguments()
                        .Return(virtualPath);
```

Comment: @womp, thanks mate. In your example what is virtualPath, an existing variable? What I'm after is to return the variable that was actually passed to ApplyAppPathModifier. This isn't know till runtime. I actually got it to work using my comment above and will post it now

Comment: If you want to know the arguments passed to ApplyAppPathModifier, you can use the code of womp and add the following line: 
var args = response.GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn(x => x.ApplyAppPathModifier(Arg<String>.Is.Anything));