# Moq equivalent to Rhino Mock's GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn

Tags: moq, rhino-mocks

trying to inspect and argument and need to retrieve it. what is the equivalent in Moq? or a way to do it in Moq?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

figured it out, utilizing the callback functionality on the Mock Setup

```
int captured_int;

mocked_obj.Setup(x => x.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Callback<int>(x => captured_int = x);
```

if your method has multiple params

```
int captured_int;
object captured_object;

mocked_obj.Setup(x => x.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
    .Callback<int, object>((i, o) => {
                                         captured_int = i;
                                         captured_object = o;
                                     });
```

then you can do asserts on the captured values;

Comment: Haha, I was trying to do the reverse (Rhino equivalent to Moq). Linking an answer to the reverse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020673/what-would-this-moq-code-look-like-in-rhinomocks

Answer (score 0):

Since Moq 4.9.0 you can access the list of invocations of the mocked object and do the asserts on those without the need for a callback:

```
[Test]
public void TestMoq()
{
    var someClass = new Mock<ISomeClass>();

    someClass.Object.SomeMethod(42, null);
    someClass.Object.SomeMethod(88, "Hello");

    // First invocation
    Assert.AreEqual(42, (int) someClass.Invocations[0].Arguments[0]);
    Assert.IsNull(someClass.Invocations[0].Arguments[1]);

    // Second invocation
    Assert.AreEqual(88, (int) someClass.Invocations[1].Arguments[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual("Hello", someClass.Invocations[1].Arguments[1]);
}
```

Of course this is just an example, in real world code you have to be more careful with this method, mostly because all the arguments are accessible as `object`s, instead of typed arguments as in the `Callback`. Also the invocations are not tied to a `Setup`, it's a list of **all** the invocations on the mocked class.